# Search results - adding "hide" capability alongside "favorite"/heart

Tags: gui-design, search

If you were to add a "hide this result" capability to a site like Airbnb, how/where would you do it?

i.e. you search and get dozens or hundreds of results and start to drill down into them. While there are some you want to "heart"/favorite, there are many you want to hide and never see again, such as if you modify your search locations or budget, etc. This is particularly useful because most users tweak their search multiple times (e.g modifying locations, budget, bedrooms, etc) yet a lot of the results are the same every time, including ones they've already looked at and ruled out. I would instead like to save them from having to see ones they already know they don't want.

Today on a site like Airbnb, they have the heart icon at top right of the photo. If I were to add a hide icon (e.g. trash can), what would be the best UI for that? i.e. I could locate it to the top left with equal prominence, or switch it to the top left and have trash at the top right instead, so that the heart comes first, like this:

[image]

The actual icons used are not too important here (and have been discussed in other questions in this site) but rather what the best UX is for users.

Comment: Is this a reasonable representation of the 'card' or 'cell' of content?  For example, is there additional text that appears below the image?  This matters because the placement of the action buttons needs to be designed relative to the visual flow for the user.  Also, how often do you think users will click on `hide` vs `favorite`?

Comment: Yes, there will be content below the image, e.g. the name, price range, construction year, etc. There will also be some form of "Details" link/button which when clicked will open up the full details of the accommodation on a new tab. I think that users who understand the feature would end up hiding as many or more than they favourite.

Comment: OK.  It would be good practice to provide a wireframe of the full card (use dummy title and description) rather than just the graphic, because that context is essential for determining placement.

Answer (score 2):

Given the complementary nature of the two functions, I would visually place them next to each other, with a tooltip or some other text hint educating on what result can be expected from each interaction. Don't make the user go in multiple directions to "vote" on a selection.

To support a user's ability to undo, I would also explore a global "clear" or "reset" function.